# Is Standard ML compiled, interpreted or both?

Tags: sml, compiled, interpreted-language

Is the functional programming language Standard ML (SML) compiled, interpreted or both?

From what I have researched, I see that it is a compiled language. Is there an explanation as to why for this?

Comment: Being compiled or interpreted is not a property of languages.

Comment: Rather, it's a property of _implementations_ of languages.

Comment: Plus... `both`, I think can't be at the same time... There could be parts which are compiled, and other parts interpreted... But same part cannot be both at the same time.